# Should we clean up the Xcode-6 related tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are at least nine Xcode 6-related tags:

- [xcode6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6) (3729 questions)
- [xcode6gm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6gm) (52 questions)
- [xcode6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6.1) (301 questions)
- [xcode6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6.0.1) (19 questions)
- [xcode6-beta4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6-beta4), [xcode6-beta5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6-beta5), [xcode6-beta6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6-beta6) and [xcode6-beta7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6-beta7) (93, 32, 79 and 24 questions, respectively)
- [xcode6.1-gm-seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6.1-gm-seed) (8 questions)

There was also an [xcode6-beta3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6-beta3) tag, but that's become a synonym of [xcode6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6).

I see two problems with these tags:

- **Too many tags.** I think it's unnecessary and confusing to have so many tags for Xcode, and I'd condense it to just [xcode6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6) and [xcode6-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6-beta). (I'm on the fence about having a separate [xcode6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6.1) tag.)
- **The tag is being used indiscriminately.** The tag wiki for [xcode6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6) reads:

  > This tag should only be used for questions about Xcode itself, and not for general Mac or iOS programming topics.

  but especially in the beta tags, this doesn't seem to be the case.

There are few enough questions in each of the small tags that they can probably be cleaned up by hand, either retagging the question with a more common tag, or removing the tag as appropriate. But I don't want to take a hatchet to those tags without getting some other opinions.

**What do other people think we should do about these tags?**

Comment: Unfortunately the indiscriminately use is not limited to the beta tags. [tag:xcode] is basically used as an umbrella tag for everything that is related to iOS/OS X development.